# Cannot get JDBC driver to work in tomcat jsp

Tags: mysql, jsp, tomcat, jdbc

I try to make a simple example connection to a mysql database in jsp running on tomcat.

Running the code below I get the response: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/TestingDB

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD><TITLE>Testing mysql</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY>

<%@ page import = "java.sql.*"%>

<%  
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/TestingDB";

        String user = "mysql";
        String password = "pwd";

    try {
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        out.println("Success");
        Statement st = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        st = con.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM TestTable");
        while(rs.next()){ 
            out.println(rs.getString("String1"));
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
%>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I have put the mysql-connector-java-5.1.xx-bin.jar in the CATALINA_HOME/lib directory and when it did not work I tried to put it in the {appname}/WEB-INF/lib directory.

I have restarted tomcat between each try using *services* *tomcat* *restart*.

There should not be any problems accessing the database as it works fine using (pretty much) the same code in a standalone java class.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

class JDBCTest {

    private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/TestingDB?useSSL=false";

    private static final String user = "mysql";     
    private static final String password = "pwd";

    public static void main(String args[]) {
            try {
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            System.out.println("Success");
            Statement st = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            st = con.createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM TestTable");
            while(rs.next()){ 
                  System.out.println(rs.getString("String1"));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm really running out of ideas. All help is welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have put the mysql-connector-java-5.1.xx-bin.jar in the CATALINA_HOME/lib directory

That should work, but you would have to restart Tomcat before testing it.

> and when it did not work I tried to put it in the {appname}/WEB-INF/ directory.

Wrong. Should be the `{appname}/WEB-INF/lib` directory.

Howver you should be defining this database as a Resource in your META-INF/context.xml and getting it from Tomcat via a JNDI lookup on the `java:comp/env/jdbc`  namespace. What you're doing is poor practice.

Comment: Thank you. I did restart tomcat inbetween and I just missed the _/lib_ on that directory. I'm total beginner at this stuff and have followed tutorials. I you say it is bad practice I will look into that as well (especially as it does not work now).

Comment: After creating another webapp the proper way it does work but I don't really know why (I can just assume it is related). Thus I proclaim this the correct answer as doing it the proper way eliminates this pitfall.

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to put the port in the URL access.

Here is a simple example for a connection URL:

jdbc:mysql://localhost:**3306**/TestingDB;

Comment: It should not be a problem however as it works in the java class. I have tried adding it but it makes no difference so I actually removed it again.

Comment: It is not necessary to put the port if it is the default, as it is in this case.